# Adding index to optimize MySQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

We have the following MySQL table with about 150 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `value1` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL,
  `value2` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL,
  `value3` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL,
  `value4` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL,
  `value5` decimal(12,6) NOT NULL,
  `symbol_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`symbol_id`,`datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The 150 million rows are evenly split between 9500 symbols, designated by symbol_id.

I am trying to run the following query on the table:

```
SELECT datetime FROM data WHERE symbol_id = 1234 AND datetime <= "2013-03-01 15:00:00" ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

Running an EXPLAIN on the query returns:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: data
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 12
          ref: NULL
         rows: 23856
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

The query takes about 300ms on average to run. What index could I add to make this faster?

Thanks!

Comment: 300 ms to go through 350 million rows is pretty good.  Perhaps you need to think about upgrading your hardware to meet your performance specs.

Comment: Use `INDEX` on `value` fields too?

Comment: its actually 150 millions rows, but the thing is the query runs very fast for certain symbols but not all..

Comment: What you have now seems to be the optimal index for this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gordon hint at, there's no index which will improve the performance of your query.

That's not to say there's nothing you can do to make it faster - tune your DBMS and OS I/O - you've not provided any info about how it is currently configured nor what it's running on nor what the usage patterns are like. If you've not started this process then running mysqltuner.pl against your installation would be a good start - but it's not always completely correct. Using a different engine may improve performance for this query - but it depends on everything else going on on your system.

You'll get big gains by sharding the index across multiple disks and/or using SSDs for the index storage. More memory *nearly* always helps.

Go [get a good book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Performance-MySQL-Optimization-Replication/dp/1449314287/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1362264104&sr=8-2) on MySQL tuning, spend time reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of this query can possibly be improved with an index but first you must determine the cardinality of your columns.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `datetime`) FROM `data`;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `symbol_id`) FROM `data`;
```

Whichever returns the highest number of unique values has a higher cardinality and to have an optimal composite index, the columns must be in descending order of cardinality.

You currently have a composite primary key with columns in the following order.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`symbol_id`,`datetime`)
```

If symbol_id has a higher cardinality than datetime then the query cannot be optimized further. On the other hand, if datetime has a higher cardinality then you should add an index with datetime followed by symbol_id.

```
INDEX idx_datetime_symbol (`datetime`,`symbol_id`)
```